# Spark rdd1 and rdd2 do inner join, new value is the value in rdd1

Tags: python, apache-spark, mapreduce, hdfs, rdd

I have two RDD `rdd1` and `rdd2`

```
rdd1 = [(key1,value11), (key2,value12)]
rdd2 = [(key1, value21), (key3, value22)]
```

Now I'm going to do a inner join with `rdd1` and `rdd2` and an example result like this

```
rdd_join = [(key1,value11)]
```

In sql it would be something like this

```
SELECT rdd1.key,rdd1.value 
FROM rdd1
INNER JOIN rdd2
WHERE rdd1.key = rdd2.key
```

Any idea?

Comment: If you create dataframes from your RDDs, you can simply do `val joined = df1.join(df2, $"df1Key" === $"df2Key", "inner")`

Answer (score 0):

```
joined_rdd = rdd1.join(rdd2)
```

But this will not give you what you exactly want but

```
[joined_rdd = [(key1, (value11, value21))]
```

Your example above is not a join.  You can get what you want from the joined data by `joined_rdd.map(lambda l: [l[0], l[1][0]])` or by using filter instead of join in the first place